# showing Alphabets in spinner

Tags: java, android, android-widget, spinner

Howdy, 
I am writing a GRE app on android.i am new in this arena.

I want to show all the alphabets in the spinner control. what is best way to do it and how can I do it. Can some share the code.

Like in .NET , i would have filled an array with all the chars A-Z. then have called toChar and bind it with combo control.

I dont how to did the same think java and android ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do a search first, Anyway here is the tutorial
http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/views/hello-spinner.html